# Zalgo text invades Security.SE

Tags: discussion

Zalgo text (http://textozor.com/zalgo-text/) takes advantage UTF8 and rendering. Some, like the user profile below are relatively benign. Some, not so much. The user below is brand new to Security.SE.

Question: Should we encourage users to remove zalgo text? Some devices may not respond well to it.

https://security.stackexchange.com/users/114005/andrew-sun%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae%cd%88%cc%ae

Comment: I wonder what it looked like. ☺

Comment: I̹̩̬̮̗̘̺͛͆ͧͨ ̦ǵ̨͒ͪ̅͋́ȕ͖̤̘̽̒̆̍̓̋e̴͔͙̩͎̟̪s͉͉̫̱̱͕ͮ̉͒͑̃̒ŝ̮̝͈͒ͪ̽ ͍̦̦̳̊̈͆̐̈́i͕̺̬̙̰̦͋̈́̿ͣt̢̤̏ ̰̘̺̩̳͎͙ĺ̯͙̠͚̤̉ͬ̈o̧̹ͫǒ͆̊͗͐͆̚҉̼̱k̪͛̑ͤ̾̏̎ẹ̫̫͔͓̳̭̾d̷̘̀̓ͨͭͧ̐ ̴̲̹͙͊̊̽̀̏̈l̗͍͈͍̯͇ͤi̱̮̹̭̝̒͋̔͊̔ͯ͟k͓̩̋͆́̍͂ͬ͜e̲̩̲̼̹͍ͣͪ̋̚͟ ̲͍̳̱̠ͩ̐̕t͍͛ͫ͗͝h̷͉͉̖̺̼̟͇i̤͈̬̮̘͉̰͐̄ͧ̈̒̚͟s͚̝̤̫͓̠.̭͕̝͇̉͗ͣ̕ ̯͈̹̟̗͛ͥ̇̉̏͡l̖͕̎̎͋͊̂͆̎ő̓҉͇̳̟̹̙̱ͅl̘̮͖͇͕̊ͤ͋͂̅ͫ͘

Comment: ɐɔʇnɐןןʎ, there's some ¢σσℓ тнιηgѕ уσυ ¢αη ∂σ ฬเtђ tђคt รเtє. Especially !f y0u (4n r34d 7h!5.

Comment: Incidently one of the most famous answers on SO uses Zalgo to good efect. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/537897

Comment: Hey, that was me͈̮͈̮͈̮͈̮͈̮͈̮͈̮͈̮͈̮͈̮!

Comment: +1 for your profile text: *"Maybe I shouldn't prefer to keep an air of mystery about myself."*

Comment: sǝɯoɔ ǝɥ ʎɐs ʎǝɥʇ

Comment: I have been aware of the HTML / Regex "answer" for a while, but never knew how it was done. Now I do. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks - this is a good call. Generally, unless a username is flagged as offensive, we leave them alone, however after testing this with a varied set of devices, I'd have to agree - it does break things badly on one of my Android phones.

I'll edit and leave a note for the user in this instance - and please flag up further instances that cause rendering issues.